Excel data copy with multiple filters in pivot table to another excel
I have an excel which has inputs to be entered in multiple sheets after which a pivot table in one of the sheets is to refreshed with filters as per the needs. This then updates another table which takes data from the first pivot table and a table. For each need, the table is to be copied to another excel. This task to be repeated for different needs scenario. How can this task be automated?
I know some basic power query technics. But this does not look to know in my knowledge so far. My understanding is that can macro can be helpful in this case. The excel itself is pretty huge about 50MB. So I doubt opening and refreshing with macro make it slower. The excel itself is slow now.
So I am struck with no solution. Need ideas to deep dive for a path please.
